# How to use param from HTTP request to append a model in Django

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, django-views

I am new to Django and how it interacts with some of its internal components so I apologize in advance if this is obvious. I am working with html canvas and a particular javascript library (fabric.js) so that I can convert a canvas to a json object. I want to use an ajax request to send that json object so that I can attach it to a model in my db. How would I go about doing this.

Here is the Javascript:

```
function postData(input) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: window.location.href,
                data: { json: input },
                success: callbackFunc
            });
        }
let canvasBefore = JSON.stringify(canvas);
postData(canvasBefore);
```

I assume there is an built in method for django to handel requests like this. Thank you for the help.
Nicholas

Answer (score 0):

If `canvas` is the actual `<canvas>` element, you can't just `JSON.stringify()` it and expect an image to get saved:

```
>>> c = document.createElement('canvas')
    <canvas>​
>>> JSON.stringify(c)
    "{}"
```

Instead, you may want to use `canvas.toDataURL()` to get a [`data:` URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) that encodes the content of the canvas in Base64 encoded PNG format:

```
>>> x = c.toDataURL()
    "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA..."
```

That is a plain string you could save into a Django model, or better yet, decode back into binary PNG in your server-side code and save as a file using a `FileField` or even `ImageField`.

Comment: I don't want to save it as an image,  I want to keep the json so that the user can go back to the canvas and continue editing the canvas where they left off. A feature of fabric.js is that it is possible to load from a json. But thank you for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Well i think the best way is using [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/), with this library you can create powerful APIs the process would by something like this:

1. Create a [Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/)
2. Create a [ModelSerializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) (DRF needed)
3. Create a View to handle the request in this case you can use the [CreateApiView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createapiview) class. (DRF needed)
4. Create your [endpoint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/)
5. Use it

There are many ways to create a solution for your problem, this is only one of them. I hope it helps you.